# Scrolling in a Scroll View when keyboard is up (like in the Notes Application iOS )

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, textfield

I could unhide my text field when the keyboard comes up, but the problem now is that I want the user to be able scroll in the view and see other stuff which was above the text field even when the keyboard is up. Just like you can do it in the notes application, you can scroll in the notes even when the keyboard up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions :

• Resize the frame of your scrollView with a height that's perfectly to your keyboard.

• Change the contentOffset of your scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Register for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`, get the keyboard size and animation speed and resize the scroll view.